# qt creator - variable view display garbage

Tags: c++, qt

[image]

I'm new at QT (4.8) and C++. I tried attaching the QT Creator to a running application for debugging purposes. Breakpoints are hit and I can easily traverse the code using F10, F11.

But the problem is I can't see any of the content of the variables I am debugging. They all appear to contain members and properties that are not usefull such as "d", "data", "shared_empty". Where is the actual content of the variable? Even a simple Qstring does not show it's content.

The image in the documentation shows a Qstring and its content.
http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debug-mode.html
How come I cannot see it when debugging my code?

Comment: The string content should be in `data`. For me the string value is also listed next to the string instance identifier, but for you it's missing, Maybe it is because of old Creator or debugger version. Your Qt version is quite old for sure.

Comment: There is nothing under data for me )-: